# R Slow Stochastic quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to reproduce [this chart](http://stockcharts.com/h-sc/ui?s=SPY&p=D&b=5&g=0&id=p36114342617) in R using quantmod, however I cannot seem to get the same result for the slow stochastic. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
library(quantmod, quietly=TRUE)
getSymbols("SPY", from="2013-01-01")
chartSeries(SPY, subset='last 3 months')
addSMI(n=5,slow=5,fast=1,signal=1,ma.type="SMA")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first off, you're not going to be able to calculate slow stochastic with the `SMI` (stochastic momentum index) function. :)

Second, there's no `addStochastics` function. You need to use `stoch` to calculate the value you need, then `addTA` to add it to the chart. The code below seems to get fairly close to the chart in your link.

```
chartSeries(SPY, subset='2015', TA="addTA(stoch(HLC(SPY), 5, 1, 3, 'SMA')$slowD)")
```

Comment: Thank you. Close enough for my purposes.